# Facebook Login using PHP SDK in CakePHP 3x

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk, cakephp-3.0

Is there any reference for Facebook login integration(PHP SDK) in CakePHP 3(beta 2)? 
I tried using  [GITHUB PHP SDK-4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4)
And the error I get is

```
Error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession' not found
```

Comment: You tried _what exactly_? Have you read **https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0**?

Comment: Yes, fixed the issues and its working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed the documentations and integrated Facebook Login in CakePHP 3x version. Its working perfect as expected! Referred the Facebook developers forum. Its much convenient to start with. Good luck if you are about to start!